# Can't get a ul to span across column

Tags: html, css

I have a ul within a div in a column. I am having trouble getting the ul to span across the column. I tried using column-span: all; and width: 100%;, but nothing seems to be working. Below is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve, and what it looks like now. Also below is the code pertaining to it. Any help would be great!

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]

What it currently looks like:
[image]

HTML: (I gave the second li a class because it needs to be wider than the other two as you can see in the picture above)

```
<div class="news-events group">
  <div class="col1">
    <h1>News & Press Releases</h1>

    <?php query_posts('post_type=issues&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full_size' );
      $url = $thumb['0']; ?>

      <div class="post-container container-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?=$url?>');">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More ></a>
      </div>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>View All</li>
        <li class="gi">Get Involved</li>
        <li>Next Page</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.news-events {
  background-image: url('images/front-page-bg.jpg');
  padding: 25px 75px;
}

.news-events .col1 {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

.news-events .col1 h1 {
  color: white;
}

.news-events .col1 .post-container {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.news-events .col1 .post-container h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.news-events .col1 .post-container p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  width: 75%;
}

.news-events .col1 .post-container a {
  color: black;
}

.news-events .col1 .container-2, .news-events .col1 .container-4 {
  color: white;
}

.news-events .col1 .container-2 a, .news-events .col1 .container-4 a {
  color: white;
}

.news-events .col1 .navigation {
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  column-span: all;
}

.news-events .col1 .navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.news-events .col1 .navigation ul li {
  padding: 15px 35px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -7px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.news-events .col1 .navigation ul .gi {
}
```

Comment: What is the css for gi? And can you include the rest of the code because there may be something surrounding the code that may effect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your code

```
.news-events .col1 .navigation ul li {
    width:25%
}
.news-events .col1 .navigation ul li.gi {
    width:50%
}
```

Edit:
Or remove the class in your li and at this to your code

```
.news-events .col1 .navigation ul li {
    width:25%
}
.news-events .col1 .navigation ul li:nth-child(2) {
    width:50%
}
```

Comment: lol... always the simplest things you overlook. Thanks a lot!